# BlockingIOError: [Errno 35] Resource temporarily unavailable

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, python-multiprocessing

I am using Python 3.7 and relying on **multiprocessing** library , my code simply uses the requests library, and I always ran out `BlockingIOError: [Errno 35] Resource temporarily unavailable`
even-though I tried to except the error but no luck .

Error traceback :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sort.py", line 204, in <module>
    p.start()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 112, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/context.py", line 223, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/context.py", line 277, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py", line 20, in __init__
    self._launch(process_obj)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py", line 70, in _launch
    self.pid = os.fork()
BlockingIOError: [Errno 35] Resource temporarily unavailable
```

my code :

```
    headers = {
// ..
    }

    proxy = {
    'http': 'http://'+Proxy,
    "https": 'https://'+Proxy

        }
        req = requests.post(url,headers=headers,data=data,timeout=10,proxies=proxy)
```

Anyone knows whats wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. I am familiar with a different signature for the request - which is:

   ```
   resp = requests.request("POST", url, data=json.dumps(payload), 
   headers=headers, verify=False, additional-parameters>)
   ```
2. I am seeing this issue when the `URL` being requested does not respond and the request times-out.  Did you check your using "curl" to see if it is correct?